# Access to the path \\otherserver\inputs_for_import_only\AllOutputs\abcd.pdf' is denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am getting access denied exception while trying to get a file from another system using my asp.net web application.

these both systems are in different domains. I am able to access the file from the explorer. However I am not able to access through asp.net web application (IIS).

Could you please help me out in this?

> Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the
>   path '\otherserver\inputs_for_import_only\AllOutputs\abcd.pdf' is
>   denied.

ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7, and the configured application pool identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if the application is not impersonating. If the application is impersonating via , the identity will be the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated request user.

To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in Explorer, choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add" to add the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account, and check the boxes for the desired access.

Answer (score 0):

You Web application runs on different user account , check the identity under which you application is running and then provide access to that user account.

Comment: Thanks for you response. I have set "NetworkService" as identity in IIS. I am very new to IIS settings. What should be as the "identity" value in IIS?

Comment: It is not in the "Windows authentication" mode.

Comment: Access policy to this shared folder has been given as "Full control"

Comment: This application is running in II7